# Firebase Analytics and 3rd party cookies

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics

Currently I'm using firebase analytics in my app like so

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "-----",
  authDomain: "------",
  projectId: "-------",
  storageBucket: "-------",
  messagingSenderId: "-------",
  appId: "-------",
  measurementId: "-------"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
initializeAnalytics(app, {
  config: {
    cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None; Secure; Partitioned'
  }
})
```

As you can see, I'm trying to setup my analytics in a way that prevents the following issue in the dev console

```
Cookies with the SameSite=None; Secure and not Partitioned attributes that 
operate in cross-site contexts are third-party cookies. In future Chrome versions, 
reading third-party cookies will be blocked. This behavior protects user data from cross-site tracking.
```

I haven't seen much from firebase on how to prevent this issue, so wasn't sure how to resolve. I've tried adding the `cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None; Secure; Partitioned'` but still getting the issue in my devtools. Anyone know whats going on here?